# Windows Phone MVVM + Prism --- Convert Event to a command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone

I am having trouble converting an eventhandler into a command using MVVM design and the Prism toolkit.

I'm also using the WPToolkit -- the DatePicker. I need to set the ValueChanged event to a command.

Here's my code:

MainPageViewModel

```
_setDateOne = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
     { });

void picker1_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
   using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
   if (isf.FileExists("DateOne"))
       isf.DeleteFile("DateOne");
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["DateOne"] = e.NewDateTime.Value;
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}
}
```

Xaml

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Name="picker1" ValueChanged="picker1_ValueChanged" Value="{Binding DateOne, ElementName=this, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I know the XAML is wrong; I don't know how to do it properly, yet.

Sorry, I'm pretty newbie with programming and especially MVVM.

Comment: If you're doing MVVM, don't use the ValueChanged event, rather implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel and in the setter of the property you've bound to the DatePickers Value invoke whatever you have planned for the valuechange command.

Comment: I do have the NotifyPropertyChanged event implemented. The code in ValueChanged is just what I want to happen when the value is changed; not sure how to actually implement it with a command.

And also, I need the DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e in order to know what to set my DateTime to.

Comment: in the setter for DateOne, `set { DateOne = value; CallYourMethodHere(value); }`

Comment: Since my binding is TwoWay, I don't actually need the event arg, then?

Comment: Correct.  You have the value you need in the DateOne property.

Comment: You might need to add `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` to your binding, changing it to `{Binding Path=DateOne, ElementName=this, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged}`  I'm not near an IDE so I could test this for you.

Comment: PropertyChanged was not found. :/

The only options for UpdateSourceTrigger are "Default" and "Explicit".

Comment: eww... Looks like you'll have to also do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542291/datepicker-selecteddate-not-changing-when-text-is-input) to get this to work with that DatePicker.  sorry.

Comment: Not sure how to implement that :(  ...but I will try to figure it out. Thank you!!

Comment: Wait -- users don't actually type in the date, they select it from a dropdown similar to what's already built into Windows Phone -- is this the same thing I'll need?

Comment: dunno, see if you can get it working without it first :P

Comment: I've been informed that it's bed time.  good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `ValueChanged` event handler here, you can do procedure to save selected date in setter of `DateOne` :

```
private DateTime _dateOne;
public DateTime DateOne
{
    get { return _dateOne; }
    set
    {
        _dateOne = value;
        SaveDate(value);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DateOne");
    }
}

SaveDate(DateTime date)
{
    using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (isf.FileExists("DateOne"))
           isf.DeleteFile("DateOne");
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["DateOne"] = date;
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }
}
```

And assuming `DataContext` of your page has been set properly, binding this way is enough :

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Name="picker1" Value="{Binding DateOne, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```